# Typo3 extbase upload virus scan

Tags: security, typo3, antivirus, extbase

Is there any extension which can hook extbase upload with clamAV or something else?
I found this for Zend: http://www.sitepoint.com/zf-clamav/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple question, simple answer: No. You can search for extensions in the [TER (TYPO3 Extension Repository)](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/). I've already tried for several keywords in the topic, but with no success. So obviously, no extension for that (yet).